# Simple, generic way to get a value from a WPF DataContext in code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datacontext

Let's say I have a WPF control that was bound to some DataContext. Now let's say I have some UI code that needs to get some value from the DataContext. How do I do that?

---

I am aware of the following workarounds:

1. Cast the DataContext to its original type, e.g.

   ```
   var myValue = ((MyViewModel)myControl.DataContext).SomeProperty;
   ```

   or

   ```
   var myValue = ((DataRowView)myControl.DataContext).Item("SomeDatabaseField");
   ```

   I don't like this, because it means that *in my UI code* I need information about the type of the underlying data source.
2. Bind the required value to some UI field and extract it from there, e.g.

   ```
   <Button Click="..." Tag="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
   ```

   and in code

   ```
   var myValue = (TypeOfMyValue)myButton.Tag;
   ```

---

Is there some *generic* way to extract a value from a DataContext, i.e., do whatever `Binding` does to get the value? I'm looking for something like this:

```
var myValue = SomeGenericExtractMethod(myControl.DataContext, "SomeProperty");
```

I'm pretty sure that something like this exists (after all, `Binding` works like this), I just cannot find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way which works for both ViewModel classes (CLR properties) and lists bound to a ADO.NET DataTables (DataRowView fields), which is to use the [TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx) offered by both:

```
var myValue = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(myControl.DataContext)["SomeProperty"]
    .GetValue(myControl.DataContext);
```

Here is a short working example:

```
var vm = new { MyString = "Test1" };         // ViewModel

var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("MyString", typeof(String));
dt.Rows.Add("Test2");
var drv = dt.DefaultView[0];                 // DataRowView

var value1 = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(vm)["MyString"].GetValue(vm);
var value2 = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(drv)["MyString"].GetValue(drv);

// value1 = "Test1", value2 = "Test2"
```

Comment: Then my last post will be this. There is a CodeProject Entry about Typedescriptor Caching if you need to look at performance:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18450/HyperDescriptor-Accelerated-dynamic-property-acces

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Reflection. This will work for non-indexed properties:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
        var myValue = this.DataContext.GetType().GetProperty("MyIntValue").GetValue(this.DataContext, null);
    }
}

public class MyViewModel
{
    private int myIntValue = 6;
    public int MyIntValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.myIntValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, nice one for ViewModels. Won't work for controls bound to ADO.NET DataTables, though.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to build this by yourself. We did this at work, but I cannot share the code because its an internal asset. Although it's not too easy, but also not too hard thinking of also respecting indexed properties f.e.. Still it should be done in one day. You use reflection to get the values but make sure to cache the generated getters. Its not more than that. Really... :)

Maybe a litte more information on this as some people believe that is not a good way:
Given a complex propertypath you cycle through the path and resolve the objects one after another. Create a Resolver-Class that gets the DataContext-Instance. Create getter-delegates and cache those for propertytype and propertypath (just the segment). This gets really fast. The only things WPF does different is the Value-Getter. It analyses the property for its type. INotifyPropertyChanged-Supporters and DependendyObjects are treated differently, but it doesn't make much of a performance problem if you cache the delegates...

Comment: Can you please not just downvote but explain. We did this with a solid implementation. Bindings work it out the same way. Mostly by reflection...

Comment: This is a poor explanation as it is unclear what is being described. Please add minimal code examples to illustrate the solution you are proposing.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to say that one can build that for his own project. I cannot share sample code as it would break my disclosure aggreement. We use this for a WPF-Application Framework with a user base of 4k users. The resolving mechanism is used as an attachedproperty on controls, which then get configured in the background. A DataGrid f.e. gets SelectedItem, ItemsSource Bindings, SingleClick Editing, etc. You cannot just post a few lines.
In essence like I said: you want the value: resolve it via reflection in a loop, but CACHE the PropertyInfos. Just wanted to say it can be done good!

Comment: I will try to build a barebone sample just showing the caching without taking care of special cases like indexed Properties, etc. This will take a few hours...

Comment: +1, since I really appreciate the effort (although I'll probably keep using one of the workarounds if there is no built-in solution in the framework).

Comment: You are right, it takes some time to initially create this, but if you need it often it might be worth the time. Thanks for the upgrade. I am sorry I cannot proivde the original code to you.
I am pretty sure there is no way in the framework. Our LeadArchitect build the resolving mechanism as we needed a performant way to access the given PropertyPaths in CodeBehind. In addition: you can also store Attributes in the cached Structures and additional infos. I will get back to you with a barebone sample... :)

Comment: @Gope: Thanks, but don't put too much effort in it. :-) As I said, I probably won't use it (the workarounds do work fine, I just wanted to know if I'm missing something obvious in the framework), and the community does not seem to appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

//Into the View:

```
public Ingreso Ingreso { get; set; }

public CapturaDatos()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Ingreso = new Ingreso();
    DataContext = Ingreso;
}
```

//Into the model

```
internal class IngresoViewModel
{
    public Ingreso IngresoDetails { get; set; } 
}
```

//Into de View XAML

```
xmlns:modelo="clr-namespace:WpfApp2.ViewModel"
<Page.DataContext>
    <modelo:IngresoViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxCurp" TextChanged="textBoxCurp_TextChanged" CharacterCasing="Upper" Text="{Binding IngresoDetails.Curp}" />
```

Then you can use the Ingreso DataBinding in your XAML file or in your code.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76231350/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).